# In Javascript function onLoadPopulate() is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function onLoadPopulate() {
    var grid = $("#grid0");
    var numberOfRecords = grid.getGridParam("records");
    var dataFromGrid = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
    var count=0;
    var link;
    if(numberOfRecords>0){
    numberOfRecords=endNo;
    count=begNo-1;  
    }
    for ( ; count < numberOfRecords; count++) {

        var program = dataFromGrid[count].program;
        var programVal="";
        
     var programs = program.replace(/\s/g,'').split(',');
        
     for ( var i = 0; i< programs.length;i++) {
            
            if (programs[i] == "FS") {
                if (programVal == "") {
                    programVal = 'DOG';
                } else {
                    programVal = programVal.concat(",DOG");
                }
            } else if (programs[i]  == "TF") {
                console.log("in TF");
                if (programVal == "") {
                    programVal = 'CAT';
                } else {
                    programVal = programVal.concat(",CAT");
                }
        
        }
        grid.jqGrid('setCell', count + 1, 'program',
                programVal);
        }
}
```

TEST DATA:

program = **FS, TF**

result i'm getting : **DOG** but
the result i need :  **DOG,CAT**

When it is doing else if Even if programs[i] = TF it is skipping if loop inside.

Can anyone help with this JavaScript function?
I can't figure it out what is wrong.

Comment: I tried your loop with your given example and it's working for me

Comment: @freedomn-m im doing replace to remove space 
var programs = program.replace(/\s/g,'').split(',');

Comment: Good point.  Still add some debugging to see exactly what you're getting.

Comment: @freedomn-m i added console logs
 program: 0 Val FS, ​TF Replace and Split Val FS,​TF
 programs s: FS
 programs s: ​TF

Comment: Are you able to set up a complete snippet (ideally here or eg on jsfiddle.net) with html and relevant data?  See [mcve]

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1wkyntc5/) with just your code and the jqGrid code removed.  It works fine.  So must be something else, eg how you get the data (which you've stated is correct) or how you set the data.

Answer (score 0):

issue with input data consisted of special characters i used following replace and it worked

```
.replace(/[^a-z0-9,\s]/gi,'').replace(/[_\s]/g,'').split(',')
```